# Using free on a struct that has a member of the same type

Tags: c, recursion, struct, free, stack-overflow

I am a noob learning C,I have been trying to augment [Simple Object System](http://c.learncodethehardway.org/book/ex19.html).

I have a struct that looks like this:

```
struct Room
{
    Object proto;
    Monster* bad_guy;
    struct Room *north;
    struct Room *south;
    struct Room *east;
    struct Room *west;
};
```

I would like to free this:

```
void Room_destroy(void* self)
{
    Room* room=self;
    if(room->bad_guy)
        room->bad_guy->proto.destroy(room->bad_guy);
    if(room->north)
        room->north.proto.destroy(room->north);//same as Room_destroy
    if(room->south)
        room->north.proto.destroy(room->south);////same as Room_destroy
    if(room->west)
        room->north.proto.destroy(room->west);////same as Room_destroy
    if(room->east)
        room->north.proto.destroy(room->east);////same as Room_destroy
    free(room->proto.description);
    free(room);
}
```

Say there are two rooms,`Room* x` and Room* y such that x is to the `north` of `y` calling the method on `x` will call the method on `y` which will call it on `x` which will call it on `y` and this back and forth causes a deadlock.How do I solve this?

How do I free such memory to ensure that memory leaks do not occur?

## EDIT:

I tried to implement a set of functions to call this and I got both the `StackOverflow` and `Segmentation fault`:

```
    ==6446== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801ff8
    ==6446== 
    ==6446== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
    ==6446==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FF8
    ==6446==    at 0x400863: Room_destroy (ex19.c:55)
    ==6446==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
    ==6446==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
    ==6446==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
    ==6446==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
    ==6446==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
    ==6446== Stack overflow in thread 1: can't grow stack to 0xffe801fe8
    ==6446== 
    ==6446== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
    ==6446==  Access not within mapped region at address 0xFFE801FE8
    ==6446==    at 0x4A256A0: _vgnU_freeres (vg_preloaded.c:58)
    ==6446==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
    ==6446==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
    ==6446==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
    ==6446==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
    ==6446==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
    ==6446== 
    ==6446== HEAP SUMMARY:
    ==6446==     in use at exit: 605 bytes in 12 blocks
    ==6446==   total heap usage: 12 allocs, 0 frees, 605 bytes allocated
    ==6446== 
    ==6446== LEAK SUMMARY:
    ==6446==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==6446==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==6446==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==6446==    still reachable: 605 bytes in 12 blocks
    ==6446==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
    ==6446== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
    ==6446== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
    ==6446== 
    ==6446== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
    ==6446== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
    Segmentation fault
```

This is my code:

```
  void Room_destroy(void* self)
```

{
    Room* room=self;
    if(room->bad_guy)
        room->bad_guy->proto.destroy(room->bad_guy);

```
    if(room->north && !avoid(caller,room->north))
        room->north->proto.destroy(room->north);
    else
        caller=room->north;

if(room->south &&!avoid(caller,room->south))
    room->south->proto.destroy(room->south);
else
    caller=room->south;

if(room->west && !avoid(caller,room->west))
    room->west->proto.destroy(room->west);
else
    caller=room->west;

if(room->east && !avoid(caller,room->east))
    room->east->proto.destroy(room->east);
else
    caller=room->east;

free(room->proto.description);
//room->proto=NULL;
free(room);
```

}

The method avoid is here:

```
  int avoid(Room* caller,Room* room)
{
if(caller!=room)
    return 0;
return 1;
 }
```

Then there is a Map struct which looks like this:

```
  struct Map
 {
Object proto;
Room *start;
Room* location;
 };
```

On this structure I called the destroy method like this:

```
  void Map_destroy(void* self)
{
Map *map=self;
if(map->start)
{
    caller=map->start;
    map->start->proto.destroy(map->start);
}
if(map->location)
{
    caller=map->location;   
    map->location->proto.destroy(map->location);
}   

}
```

This is called when user aborts the program like this:

```
 case -1:
    printf("Giving up? You suck\n");
    if(game)
        game->proto.destroy(game);
    return 0;
```

Comment: Some sort of reference counting maybe?

Comment: why destroying a room destroy other room? This doesn't make sense. They didn't come together, they should not leave together.

Comment: I will not destroy each room,I will destroy everything at once,when the player aborts the game.

Comment: How do I implement reference counting??

Comment: You can insert all the `Room*` in a list, removing the duplicates and then destroy the items in the list. It might even be a good idea to have the list of rooms from the beginning for other purposes.

Comment: Please make it a habit to: 1) properly indent every single line of code and 2) always use braced if-then-else clauses, even for single line branches.

Comment: All of your problems can most likely get fixed by straightening out the program design. Why would it make sense to have a room destroying other rooms? Are you implementing some sort of explosion simulator?

Answer (score 0):

Let say at some point you had the method `addRoom` which added your room inside your network of rooms. You should then have a method `removeRoom` which make the opposite action.

So If your house\building\graph of room is in a state S0, then

```
S0-(add room x)-> S1 -(remove room x)-> S2.
```

`S0` must be equal to `S2`. So you can just use

```
removeRoom(network, x)
freeRoom(x);
```

To remove everything at once, you use

```
while(isEmpty(network) ){
   x = getHead(network)
   removeRoom(network, x)
  freeRoom(x);    
}
```

It is the same principle as linked lists in C

Answer (score 0):

The situation you describe is one that's handled very nicely in frameworks with automatic garbage collection.  If you do not wish to use such a framework, it may be handled reasonably using some of the smart pointer types in C++.  If you want to use standard C, you will need some way of determining when the last reference to an object disappears.  There are two general approaches that may be used for that:

- Keep a count of how many references there are to each object; increment that count on any action which creates either a persistent reference or a temporary reference which may be alive when the last persistent reference disappears, and decrement that count on the destruction of any reference whose creation caused the count to be incremented.  When the counter hits zero, delete the object.
- Maintain a garbage-collected universe of objects, and a list of all outside-world references to them.  Periodically scan the list of outside world references and tag every object referred to directly by an outside-world reference, or indirectly by an object which is reachable from an outside world reference.  Any number of outside-world references may point to any object within the GC universe, but every outside-world reference object should have have a clear owner and lifetime.

I don't know that I've seen C code to wrangle a general-purpose GC universe, though many specialized garbage collectors have certainly been implemented for various machines over the years.

Answer (score 0):

Use reference counting:
Std::shared_ptr for north and east, and std::weak_ptr for south and west.

Shared ptr count the number of references to an object and delete it when the last reference is destroyed. Weak pointers are allow u to access an object pointed to by a shared ptr, but don't add to the references. You need the weak_ptr to break the cyclic referencing here.

Comment: So,I create a `Room*[]` each for `shared_ptr` and `weak_ptr` which will list all `north`,`east` and `south`,`west` references for a `Room*` respectively.So,do I set all `weak_ptr` values to `NULL` and then `free` from  `Room*` when `shared_ptr` dependencies go to `NULL`??

Answer (score 0):

The approach with `avoid(caller, …)` cannot work (even if implemented correctly for two adjacent rooms) for longer chains of rooms; consider e. g.

```
P---Q
|   |
R---S
```

- if we start with destroying room S, we could get to room Q, from there to room P, then to room R and back to S, where we would need to recall the fourth previous room in order to detect that we came from here and not run around again, but we can't recall the fourth room with just one variable.

On the other hand, we don't need garbage collection or reference counting; it will do for a room that is visited for destruction to mark it, and not re-visit a marked room. So, what to use for the mark? You could add another member to `struct Room`, or, if `room->proto.description` always is non-NULL, use this as the marking flag, e. g.

```
void Room_destroy(void *self)
{
    Room *room = self;
    if (!room->proto.description) return;   // been here

    free(room->proto.description),
    room->proto.description = NULL;         // mark as visited
    if (room->bad_guy) room->bad_guy->proto.destroy(room->bad_guy);
    if (room->north) room->proto.destroy(room->north);  //same as Room_destroy
    if (room->south) room->proto.destroy(room->south);  //same as Room_destroy
    if (room->west)  room->proto.destroy(room->west);   //same as Room_destroy
    if (room->east)  room->proto.destroy(room->east);   //same as Room_destroy
    free(room);
}
```